# How to open Chromium-based Microsoft Edge via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, microsoft-edge, chromium

I want to open the new Edge browser (the one that runs on Chromium) through CMD/PowerShell.

How can I do it?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe"`

Comment: @Shahar Are you wanting to differentiate between two instances of Edge on your computer, or is there only one instance of Edge (the latest, Chromium-based one) installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `Start-Process -FilePath "c:\somepath\edge.exe"` ?

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one try that?

Comment: ?! I mean, isn't it obvious? He wants to start a program (edge), and the easiest way to do that is Start-Process, which has options whether or not to create a window, wait for it to close etc etc

Comment: "Obvious" depends on the knowledge of the OP. If it was **that** obvious, what would be the reason to ask for it? Please add some explanation to your answer, not to the comment section

Comment: "Obvious" should mean different things to you (reputation 2700+) and to Shahar (rep. 1). And I was answering to you :-) In any case, when Shahar tells us if he tried that or not, I'll be able to help him further.

Comment: Well, even if answers on SO should primarily help the OP to solve his specific problem, they are also meant to help others later. And regardless of the global reputation, I don't have a clue about Powershell, so if I wanted to learn it and stumble about a similar problem, I'd love to find an explanation about such code that helps me to understand it and not simply copy+paste it

Comment: @NicoHaase If you "don't have a clue about PowerShell", then maybe you should consider that when coming to the conclusion of "I don't understand what this answer is saying". I am familiar with PowerShell (though only, say, a 2 out of 10 skill-wise) and this is very obviously a PowerShell cmdlet that is intended to start a new application process based on a provided filepath. It is clear to me how this answers the question asked.